# How to center the coordinate of Annotation when using SKAnnotationView

Tags: android, annotations, maps, skmaps

I am including an annotation to my mapview using Skobbler SDK. 
It displays perfectly but my question is how should I center my image to the location of the annotation because what is happening is I need to tap the upper left of the image so the onAnnotationSelected will be called. It should be the center to be tapped.

Here's my code:

```
private void applyAnnotationOnMapView() {
    annotation = new SKAnnotation();
    annotation.setUniqueID(18);
    annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(121.048099, 14.572744));
    annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    SKAnnotationView imageView = new SKAnnotationView();
    imageView.setDrawableResourceId(R.drawable.poi_mapv2);
    imageView.setProperSize(32);
    annotation.setAnnotationView(imageView);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the offset property when creating the annotation:

Try this (onAnnotationSelected is called when tapping the image):

```
 final SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(); 
            annotation.setUniqueID(2000); 
            annotation.getLocation().setLongitude(23.593701); 
            annotation.getLocation().setLatitude(46.774959); 

            // center point of the image - tapping on an annotation will 
            // depend on 
            // this value . Also the actual gps coordinates of the 
            // annotation will 
            // be in the center of the image. 
            annotation.getOffset().setX(64); 
            annotation.getOffset().setY(64); 
            annotation.setImagePath(SKMaps.getInstance().getMapInitSettings().getMapResourcesPath() 
                    + "/.Common/ccpmedium_2d_retina.png"); 
            // real size of the image in pixels 
            annotation.setImageSize(128); 

            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
```